# Python 2.7 reverse a text by space character

Tags: python, text

i need help with this problem...
I got a string like this

```
Ana/n 
Baba/n
Cara/n
Dana/n
Ena
```

all have /n at the end for a new line...

and i need the code to do this:

```
Ena/n
Dana/n
Cara/n
Baba/n
Ana/n
```

thx in advance

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: Do you have `/n` or `\n`? Anyway, have you tried just using `split` and reversing the resulting list?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your `newline` character is `\n` and not `/n` as you've posted.

```
a = "Ana\n Baba\n Cara\n Dana\n Ena"
tokens = a.split(' ')[::-1]
```

Use the space character as the delimiter in the `split` in-built function,
and then just use a negative step slice to reverse the list of tokens obtained from the split.

You can later combine them:

```
combined = ' '.join(tokens)
```

Comment: @stefan if my post has solved your problem, please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Split, reverse and join:

```
s = 'Ana/n Baba/n Cara/n Dana/n Ena'
print '/n '.join(s.split('/n ')[::-1])
```

gives:

```
Ena/n Dana/n Cara/n Baba/n Ana
```